# Using SMT-LIB to count the number of modules using a formula

Tags: python, z3, smt, z3py, pysmt

I am not sure that this is possible using SMT-LIB, if it is not possible does an alternative solver exist that can do it?

Consider the equations

- `a < 10` and `a > 5`
- `b < 5` and `b > 0`
- `b < c < a`
- with `a`, `b` and `c` integers

The values for `a` and `b` where the maximum number of model exist that satisfy the equations when `a=9` and `b=1`.

Do SMT-LIB support the following: For each values of `a` and `b` count the number of models that satisfy the formulas and give the value for `a` and `b` that maximize the count.

Comment: What do you mean by 'module'? Are you trying to maximize the number of some other constraints that are satisfied?

Comment: Typing error, update the question, was supposed to be model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break down your goals:

- You want to enumerate all possible ways in which `a` and `b` *(...and more)* can be assigned
- For each combination, you want to count the number of satisfiable models

In general, this is not possible, as the domain of some variables in the problem might contain an infinite number of elements.

Even when one can safely assume that the domain of every other variable contains a finite number of elements, it is still highly **inefficient**.
For instance, if you had only Boolean variables in your problem, you would still have an exponential number of combination of values --and therefore candidate models-- to consider along the search.

However, it is also possible that your actual application is not that complex in practice, and therefore it can be handled by an *SMT Solver*.

The general idea could be to use some *SMT Solver API* and proceed as follows:

- `assert` the whole formula
- repeat until finish combinations of values:

  - `push` a back-track point
  - `assert` one specific combination of values, e.g. `a = 8 and b = 2`
  - repeat forever:

    - `check` for a solution
    - if `UNSAT`, exit the inner-most loop
    - if `SAT`, increase counter of models for the given combination of values of `a` and `b`
    - take the model value of any other variable, e.g. `c = 5 and d = 6`
    - `assert` a new constraint requesting that at least one of the *"other"* variables changes its value, e.g. `c != 5 or d != 6`
  - `pop` backtrack point

Alternatively, you may enumerate the possible assignments over `a` and `b` implicitly rather than explicitly. The idea would be as follows:

- `assert` the whole formula
- repeat forver:

  - `check` for a solution
  - if `UNSAT`, exit loop
  - if `SAT`, take the combination of values of your control variables from the model (e.g. `a = 8 and b = 2`), check in an internal map if you encountered this combination before, if not set the counter to `1`, otherwise increase the counter by `1`.
  - take the model value of any other variable, e.g. `c = 5 and d = 6`
  - `assert` a new constraint requesting for a new solution, e.g. `a != 8 or b != 2 or c != 5 or d != 6`

---

In the case that you are in doubt on which *SMT Solver* to pick, I would advice you to start solving your task with [*pysmt*](https://github.com/pysmt/pysmt), which allows one to choose among several *SMT engines* with ease.

---

If for your application an explicit enumeration of models is too slow to be practical, then I would advice you to look at the vast literature on *Counting Solutions of CSPs*, where this problem has already been tackled and there seem to exist several ways to approximately estimate the number of solutions of CSPs.

Comment: Nice analysis Patrick! But as I mentioned in the other comment, # of SAT calls you will be making with this "trick" is (in the worst case) `d^n`; where `n` is the number of variables and `d` is the cardinality of the domain. Even for small/finite domains, this number is going to be prohibitively expensive as `n` increases. I do think SMTLib is just the wrong medium to tackle this problem. Your idea of looking into "Counting Solutions of CSPs" is likely the most fruitful approach: Do you have a pointer to some light reading about techniques/tools in that realm?

Comment: @LeventErkok Sometimes `d^n` problems require `d^n` solutions, or being replaced by a trade-off. I am not sure whether I would say that *SMT* solvers should be considered as being particularly bad at this task wrt. other types of tools --unless one accepts approximate answers--, although I can see how the *lazy SMT schema* --especially without aggressive early pruning calls-- might not have brilliant performance. Perhaps model-based SMT solvers might perform better.

Comment: Regarding your request, approaches depend on the actual constraints in the problem, which were omitted by the OP, so it's hard to say. The paper *"Counting Solutions of CSPs: ..."* by *Gilles Pesant* lists a few samples of approximate counting of solutions, with appropriate citations. It could be the right place to get started surfing through the literature.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I guess we'll have to wait for Johan to experiment and report back on how well it works in practice! Johan: Please do report back your findings.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this in general; that is, when you can have arbitrary constraints over arbitrary theories. You are asking a "meta"-question: "Maximize the number of models" is not a question about the problem itself, but rather about the models of the problem; something SMTLib cannot deal with.

Having said that, however, I think it should be possible to code it for specific problems. In the example you gave, the model space is maximized when `a - b` is the greatest; so you can simply write:

```
(set-option :produce-models true)

(declare-fun a () Int)
(declare-fun b () Int)
(declare-fun c () Int)

(assert (< 5 a 10))
(assert (< 0 b  5))
(assert (< b c  a))

(maximize (- a b))
(check-sat)
(get-value (a b))
```

To which z3 responds:

```
sat
((a 9)
 (b 1))
```

as desired. Or, you can use the Python bindings:

```
from z3 import *

a, b, c = Ints('a b c')
o = Optimize()
o.add(And(5 < a, a < 10, 0 < b, b < 5, b < c, c < a))
o.maximize(a - b)

if o.check() == sat:
    m = o.model()
    print "a = %s, b = %s" % (m[a], m[b])
else:
    print "unsatisfiable or unknown"
```

which prints:

```
a = 9, b = 1
```

There are also bindings for C/C++/Java/Scala/Haskell etc. that let you do more or less the same from those hosts as well.

But the crucial point here is that we had to manually come up with the goal that maximizing `a - b` would solve the problem here. That step is something that needs human intervention as it applies to whatever your current problem is. (Imagine you're working with the theory of floats, or arbitrary data-types; coming up with such a measure might be impossible.) I don't think that part can be automated magically using traditional SMT solving. (Unless Patrick comes up with a clever encoding, he's quite clever that way!)

Comment: The document "The SMT-LIB Standard Version 2.6" does no contain `maximize`, Does z3 support an extension of SMT-LIB that also includes the keyword `maximize`?

Comment: Yes, optimization (i.e., `minimize`, `maximize` calls) are z3/OptiMathSAT extensions.

Comment: In essence, this works provided that one already knows that given a specific pattern/shape of solution, the number of models is maximized, and then one just writes an objective function which moves the search towards the desired assignment. My objection to this approach is that, if we knew in advance how to shape this ranking function (which returns the *#* of models for each combination of values, or something equivalent) then we wouldn't need to perform any search at all, but simply evaluate it. Does it also make sense to you?

Comment: That was precisely my point Patrick! The problem as it is cannot be coded in SMTLib; but individual instances can be solved. (Just like halting problem is unsolvable in general) but given a "specific" function, you are most likely prove it halts with a semi-automated tool; something theorem provers do routinely.) Any "counting" based method is going to be intractable for anything except toy instances.